# Showing an Array using JSON from Database in Ember

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json, ember.js

Well, I guess I am encountering a bit of an issue again here. I will explain what I am trying to do.

I have a `teammembers` template in which I want to show Team Members & their specific information from a specific team. For that I have to join 3 tables.

This query should give you an idea:

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams_members tm
inner join members m on tm.members_member_id=m.id
inner join teams t on tm.team_team_id=t.id
WHERE 
t.team_name='Vancouver Canuck'
```

What I initially thought that I can make a simple array and simply do `pushObject`. But It's not working & and moreover, how would I show them?

Here's what I tried:

```
App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.TeammembersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    teammembers : [], //This is for getTeamMembers Action, Coming as undefined 
    selectedTeam : null,
    team : function() {
        var teams = [];
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/getTeamNames",
            success : function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.teams.length; i++) {
                    var teamNames = data.teams[i];
                    teams.pushObject(teamNames);
                }
            }
        });
        return teams;
    }.property(),

    actions : {
        getTeamMembers : function() {

            teamName = this.get('selectedTeam.team_name');
            data = {
                team_name : this.get('selectedTeam.team_name'),
            };
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(teamName)) {

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/getTeamMembers",
                    data : data,
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.teammembers.length; i++) {
                            var teamNames = data.teammembers[i].firstname;
                            teammembers.pushObject(teamNames);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return teammembers;
                console.log(teammembers);
            } else {

            }

        }
    }
});
```

I am getting `teammember` array as undefined in this. **The snippet in `actions` will be responsible for spitting out Team Member's information when Team Name is selected from Ember.Select.**

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/59272/christopher-swasey, I was able to re-use my snippet here:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="teammembers">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                <h4>Your Team Members</h4>
                {{view Ember.Select
                contentBinding="team"
                optionValuePath="content.team_name"
                optionLabelPath="content.team_name"
                selectionBinding="selectedTeam"
                prompt="Please Select a Team"}}
                <button class="btn"
                {{action 'getTeamMembers' bubbles=false }}>Get Team Members</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Moreover, **what will user do, he will select the team from Ember.Select & when he clicks the button, somewhere I should be able to spit out team members & their information**. In future, I might want to grab ids and delete them from server as well. How would I do that as well?

So, should I use custom views or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with the code that populates properties from ajax. For example the code of property `team` of `App.TeammembersController` does the following

1.initializes a local  array variable `teams`

2.uses ajax to retrieve **asynchronously** the data from server

2.1.meanwhile the `teams` array within the ajax callback gets populated but never returned at the proper state of including data. It is required to set the controller's property once the teams array has been populated with the data. Then ember's binding will take care of the rest (populate controller's property, notify any other object interested, event the template to render the results)

3.and returns the empty `teams` array

So, you need to add two lines of code as follows,

```
team : function() {
        var teams = [];
        var self = this;/*<- */
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/getTeamNames",
            success : function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.teams.length; i++) {
                    var teamNames = data.teams[i];
                    teams.pushObject(teamNames);
                }
                self.set("team",teams);/*<- */
            }
        });
        return teams;
}.property()
```

The same should happen for the other properties you retrieve from ajax.

**EDIT1**

Below is an example based on your code. The code has been moved inside the IndexController and the button doing some action has been disabled for simplicity.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IbuHAgUB/1/edit

**HBS**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                <h4>Your Team Members</h4>
                {{view Ember.Select
                content=teams
                optionValuePath="content.team_name"
                optionLabelPath="content.team_name"
                selection=selectedTeam
                prompt="Please Select a Team"}}
                <button class="btn"
                {{action 'getTeamMembers' bubbles=false }} disabled>Get Team Members</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            selected team:{{selectedTeam.team_name}}
  </script>
```

**JS**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});


App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  test:"lalal",
    teammembers : [],
    selectedTeam : null,
    teams : function() {
        //var teams = [];
      var self = this;
        /*$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/getTeamNames",
            success : function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.teams.length; i++) {
                    var teamNames = data.teams[i];
                    teams.pushObject(teamNames);
                }
            }
        });*/
      setTimeout(function(){

          var data = [{team_name:'team1'}, {team_name:'team2'}, {team_name:'team3'}];//this will come from the server with an ajax call i.e. $.ajax({...})

    self.set("teams",data);

    },1000);//mimic ajax call

        return [];
    }.property(),
    actions : {
        getTeamMembers : function() {

            teamName = this.get('selectedTeam.team_name');
            data = {
                team_name : this.get('selectedTeam.team_name')
            };
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(teamName)) {

                /*$.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/getTeamMembers",
                    data : data,
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.teammembers.length; i++) {
                            var teamNames = data.teammembers[i].firstname;
                            teammembers.pushObject(teamNames);
                        }
                    }
                });*/
                return teammembers;
            } else {

            }

        }
    }
});
```

The same concept can be followed to retrieve any data from the server and modify/delete it as well. Just have in mind that all requests are *async* and within the callback functions you should update your ember app model/data, then ember bindings do all the magic.

**EDIT2**

In order to show the team members in a separate view (based on last comments) once the team is selected, either by clicking the button or from another bound property you may request via ajax the members for the selected team id (unless you have already loaded them eagerly) you can render the property of `teammembers`inside an included `view` or `partial`. For instance the same example and when the button is pressed members appear (without logic hardcoded but async lazy loaded data),

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IbuHAgUB/2/edit

**HBS**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_members">
  <i>this is a partial for members</i>
  {{#each member in teammembers}}<br/>
  {{member.firstName}}
  {{/each}}
  </script>
```

**JS**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  test:"lalal",
    teammembers : [],
    selectedTeam : null,
    teams : function() {
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function(){

          var data = [{team_name:'team1'}, {team_name:'team2'}, {team_name:'team3'}];//this will come from the server with an ajax call i.e. $.ajax({...})

    self.set("teams",data);

    },1000);//mimic ajax call

        return [];
    }.property(),
    actions : {
        getTeamMembers : function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function(){

          var data = [{firstName:'member1'}, {firstName:'member2'}];//this will come from the server with an ajax call i.e. $.ajax({...})

    self.set("teammembers",data);

    },1000);//mimic ajax call

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You might wanna see the code in `Actions`, This one is just there to populate the Ember.Select.

Comment: I think I get your answer now.

Comment: @user1601973 updated the answer with an example, hope it helps.

Comment: I still have a doubt that I am not able to explain my issue, the Ember.Select works fine for me. What I am interested in is showing the members in teams in a separate view. Though I feel I can do that using the same way.

Comment: @user1601973 yes you can use another view or partial or even call render and have another controller, plenty approaches it depends on the requirements and design of your system. Updated the answer with another example.

Comment: I was doing more or less same thing in my other templates. But the difference I was fetching data from a single table in those and this one involved three tables. Moreover the JSON contains more than one field, so I should be able to put them in same array as well & get them using like this, `members.team_desc`?

Comment: @user1601973 yes, actually you can have JSON objects of any complextiy you need and retrieve their data as you mentioned. The number of tables does not matter it all depends on the JSON structure you will be preparing on the server.